# How to restrict Application.FileDialog() to let the user only select 1 file of a particular type?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro in my workbook (which works perfectly) -

```
Dim filename As String

' select file
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    filename = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

Now, the above code allows the user to select multiple files, of any type. How do I modify it, so it only lets the user select a single file of a particular type **(.xml)**? Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

---

**Edit:** I found this code on the article linked by @Tim Williams in the comments of this post [Thanks Tim :)] -

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
.Filters.Add = "XML Files |*.xml"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Title = "Select XML file"

    If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    filename = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
```

But I am getting this error - `Compilation Error : Argument not optional` and `.Add` is getting highlighted... I tried to search for the error reason, but couldn't find relevant results... What should I do? Kindly guide...

Comment: Did you try referring to the online documentation?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog   That's typically a good place to start.  Or something like - https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-select-files-with-msoFileDialogFilePicker/

Comment: [FileDialog.Filters property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.filters) Is this what you want?

Comment: BTW do you know you can use [Application.GetOpenFilename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename) to specifiy the filters?

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for recommending the article [wellsr.com one](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-select-files-with-msoFileDialogFilePicker/)  - I am 90% through with the problem; I am facing a bug when I try to add a filter of XML filetype - please check my updated first post for more details. Kindly guide :)

Comment: `.Filters.Add "XML files", "*.xml", 1 `

Comment: Thanks a lot @TimWilliams - this works a treat :) Kindly add your comment as an answer to this question, so I could mark this done. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.filedialog has a good overview, and https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/vba-select-files-with-msoFileDialogFilePicker/ has more on using `msoFileDialogFilePicker`

Specifically you want to set:

```vba
    .AllowMultiSelect = False               'allow only 1 file to be selected
    .Filters.Add "XML files", "*.xml", 1    'select only files with "xml" extension
```